# How can I quit/pause/unpause a timer thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, timer

I am trying to build a pausable pomodoro timer, but can't figure out how my threads should be set up. Specifically I am having a hard time on finding a way to pause/quit the timer thread. Here's what I am currently trying to do:

I have an input thread collecting crossterm input events and sending them via an mpsc-channel to my main thread

My main thread runs the timer (via `thread::sleep`) and receives the input messages from the other thread

However because sleep is a blocking operation, the main thread is often unable to react to my key-events.

Any advice how I could be going about this?

Here is a minimum reproducable example:

```rust
pub fn run() {
    enable_raw_mode().expect("Can run in raw mode");

    let (input_worker_tx, input_worker_rx): (Sender<CliEvent<Event>>, Receiver<CliEvent<Event>>) =
        mpsc::channel();

    poll_input_thread(input_worker_tx);
    main_loop(input_worker_rx);
}

fn main_loop(input_worker_rx: Receiver<CliEvent<Event>>) {
    let stdout = std::io::stdout();
    let backend = CrosstermBackend::new(stdout);
    let mut terminal = Terminal::new(backend).expect("Terminal could be created");
    terminal.clear().expect("Terminal could be cleared");

    let mut remaining_time = 20;

    while remaining_time > 0 {
        if let InputEvent::Quit = handle_input(&input_worker_rx) {
            break;
        };

        remaining_time -= 1;
        let time = util::seconds_to_time(remaining_time);
        view::render(&mut terminal, &time);

        sleep(time::Duration::new(1, 0));
    }

    quit(&mut terminal, Some("Cya!"));
}



pub fn poll_input_thread(input_worker_tx: Sender<CliEvent<Event>>) {
    let tick_rate = Duration::from_millis(200);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut last_tick = Instant::now();
        loop {
            let timeout = tick_rate
                .checked_sub(last_tick.elapsed())
                .unwrap_or_else(|| Duration::from_secs(0));

            if event::poll(timeout).expect("poll works") {
                let crossterm_event = event::read().expect("can read events");
                input_worker_tx
                    .send(CliEvent::Input(crossterm_event))
                    .expect("can send events");
            }

            if last_tick.elapsed() >= tick_rate && input_worker_tx.send(CliEvent::Tick).is_ok() {
                last_tick = Instant::now();
            }
        }
    });
}

pub fn handle_input(input_worker_rx: &Receiver<CliEvent<Event>>) -> InputEvent {
    match input_worker_rx.try_recv() {
        Ok(CliEvent::Input(Event::Key(key_event))) => match key_event {
            KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char('q'),
                ..
            }
            | KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char('c'),
                modifiers: KeyModifiers::CONTROL,
                ..
            } => {
                return InputEvent::Quit;
            }

            _ => {}
        },
        Ok(CliEvent::Tick) => {}
        Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {}
        Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => eject("Input handler disconnected"),
        _ => {}
    }

    InputEvent::Continue
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including in particular the `handle_input` function. The solution is probably to avoid `sleep` and use [`crossterm::event::poll`](https://docs.rs/crossterm/0.25.0/crossterm/event/fn.poll.html) which allows specifying a timeout while waiting for events.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am already using event::poll inside the input thread. I will upload a minimal example, soon :)

Comment: I added an example, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sleep` and don't use `try_recv`. Instead use [`recv_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout) with a timeout corresponding to your `sleep` duration:

```
pub fn run() {
    enable_raw_mode().expect("Can run in raw mode");

    let (input_worker_tx, input_worker_rx): (Sender<CliEvent<Event>>, Receiver<CliEvent<Event>>) =
        mpsc::channel();

    poll_input_thread(input_worker_tx);
    main_loop(input_worker_rx);
}

fn main_loop(input_worker_rx: Receiver<CliEvent<Event>>) {
    let stdout = std::io::stdout();
    let backend = CrosstermBackend::new(stdout);
    let mut terminal = Terminal::new(backend).expect("Terminal could be created");
    terminal.clear().expect("Terminal could be cleared");

    let mut target_time = Instant::now() + Duration::from_secs(20);
    let mut paused = false;
    let mut remaining = Duration::from_secs (0);

    while paused || (target_time > Instant::now()) {
        match handle_input(&input_worker_rx, Duration::from_secs (1)) {
            InpuEvent::Quit => break,
            InputEvent::Pause => {
                if paused {
                    target_time = Instant::now() + remaining;
                } else {
                    remaining = target_time - Instant::now();
                }
                paused = !paused;
            },
            _ => {},
        }

        let time = (if paused { remaining } else { target_time - Instant::now() })
                 .as_secs();
        view::render(&mut terminal, &time);
    }

    quit(&mut terminal, Some("Cya!"));
}



pub fn poll_input_thread(input_worker_tx: Sender<CliEvent<Event>>) {
    let tick_rate = Duration::from_millis(200);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut last_tick = Instant::now();
        loop {
            let timeout = tick_rate
                .checked_sub(last_tick.elapsed())
                .unwrap_or_else(|| Duration::from_secs(0));

            if event::poll(timeout).expect("poll works") {
                let crossterm_event = event::read().expect("can read events");
                input_worker_tx
                    .send(CliEvent::Input(crossterm_event))
                    .expect("can send events");
            }

            if last_tick.elapsed() >= tick_rate && input_worker_tx.send(CliEvent::Tick).is_ok() {
                last_tick = Instant::now();
            }
        }
    });
}

pub fn handle_input(input_worker_rx: &Receiver<CliEvent<Event>>, timeout: Duration) -> InputEvent {
    match input_worker_rx.recv_timeout(timeout) {
        Ok(CliEvent::Input(Event::Key(key_event))) => match key_event {
            KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char('q'),
                ..
            }
            | KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char('c'),
                modifiers: KeyModifiers::CONTROL,
                ..
            } => {
                return InputEvent::Quit;
            }

            KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char(' '),
                ..
            } => {
                return InputEvent::Pause;
            }

            _ => {}
        },
        Ok(CliEvent::Tick) => {}
        Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {}
        Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => eject("Input handler disconnected"),
        _ => {}
    }

    InputEvent::Continue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your code seems to work. However I still have a few questions:
1. Why is the target_time code necessary? I tried it with my old solution and the timer went down way too quickly. But I don't understand why that is.
2. How would I pause the timer? As the `target_time` is relative to `Instant::now()` that seems to be rather difficult (or at least I can't quite wrap my had around it ;) )

Comment: Oh I think I know, why it counts down too fast - my input polling thread regularily sends tick events, which satisfy the `recv_timeout`...

Comment: As you found out, `target_time` is here because the timeout may not be respected: the call may return earlier or later, and `target_time` hides those irregularities.

Comment: As for pausing the timer, simply memorize the remaining time when you want to pause and recompute `target_time` when you want to resume.

Comment: See amended code for pausing on the space key.